# Add TM symbol in the subject of the email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, html-email

I need to show TM symbol in the subject of an email. I am adding it in the body of the mail using `&#8482;` as we can send the email as text/html encoding. But, I need to add this in the subject line also.

I guess this is not possible since we cannot use HTML in subject line of the email. But I want to make sure of that or maybe some other way of doing it. I am using Rails 3.

Comment: What happens if you put ™ directly?

Comment: I havent tried that..let me check.

Comment: while this might work with some email clients, it's definitely not allowed according to rfc822. Headers can only contain US-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i don't know ruby, but generally, you would encode the subject like this :

```
=?utf-8?q?hello_world=E2=84=A2?=
```

=> this produces
"hello world™"

**=E2=84=A2** is the quoted printable representation of the trademark symbol in utf-8

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word

Answer (score 0):

Add this Unicode Character trademark symbol **\u2122** in from address for ex: "**MakeMyShop\u2122 Offers"**  and in email subject like **"Welcome to MakeMyShop.IN\u2122!"**

[image]